Multi-language support for MapServer WMS without activating INSPIRE schema?
I am configuring MapServer WMS layers and need to support multiple languages. One problem is the legends, another, not necessarily related, is the capability document, so I'm posting two separate questions. This one is about the capability document, the other post about the legends is here.
Titles and abstracts in the capability document shall be returned in the language requested by a parameter. When searching for docs about MapServer multi-language support, I only found these about INSPIRE support. So I set "wms_languages" "eng,ger,fre,ita" and configured language specific WMS properties following the syntax "wms_abstract.ger" "my german abstract", and figured out that the language is requested with the parameter language. But other languages than the default are only returned if I also activate wms_inspire_capabilities (by setting it to url or embed). But if I do so, the capabilities document contains warnings about missing INSPIRE fields.
Do I really need to activate the INSPIRE schema just to be able to use language specific titles and abstracts?
Example from the Swiss Federal Office of Topography swisstopo which is language specific, but without INSPIRE schema: https://wms.geo.admin.ch/?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&lang=de (compare with lang=fr)

The answer is surely no, because the Swiss service is doing it, though the Swiss service isn't INSPIRE compliant, because it doesn't use three letter language code, the language parameter, or have an extended capabilities response. It probably as per your link is using run-time substitution, though may have another mechanism, such as a proxy...
